# ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue

Tags: java, android

I have android program but my list view doesn't work correctly.
if list view has more item with scrolling when i am going to click last checkbox with scrolling its check another item. please find my code sample.please help me to resolve this.

This my code for getView for adapter class

```
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unsettled_invoice_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.usinvoicedesc);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.selected);
            holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            vi.setTag(holder);
            vi.setTag(R.id.selected, holder.chkbox);
        } else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        if(data.size()<=0){
            holder.desc.setText("No Data");
        }else{
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = (Invoice)data.get(position);
            if(mode == 1){
                 int myColor =  Color.rgb(0, 128, 0);
                 if(tempValues.getStatus() == 2){
                        myColor = Color.rgb(0, 128, 0);     // Green        
                        holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
                 }else if(tempValues.getStatus() == 3){
                         myColor = Color.rgb(128, 0, 0);    // Red
                         holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
                 } 
                 holder.desc.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
            }
             holder.desc.setText(tempValues.toString());
             vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position));
        }
        return vi;
    }
```

This is layout.xml which i used for android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:textColor="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/usinvoicelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="0dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usinvoicedesc"
            android:layout_width="520dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/selected"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think there are a lot of question and solution for your problem . try search

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to maintain a hashmap. When you clicked on checkbox put position in hashmap and in getview before set checkbox checked check position in hashmap. if exist then checked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link:
It is specific solution for your issue of another item checkbox checked on scroll:

http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

In above Link example in your listview Adapter class getView() method add below code:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
```

and for checkbox click add below code:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
    }
});
```